# Elements redefined while adding content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have this code:

```
<ul id="ul"></ul>
<script>
    var playlist = document.getElementById('ul');

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = 'innerHTML';
    playlist.appendChild(li);

    console.log(playlist.children[0] === li); // true

    playlist.innerHTML += 'some text';

    console.log(playlist.children[0] === li); // false
    console.log(playlist.children[0]); // <li>innerHTML</li>
    console.log(li); // <li>innerHTML</li>
</script>
```

Weird thing is, while first comparation returns `true`, after adding 'some text', it isn't equal anymore. Why is that? Is it a bug, or intended behaviour? Is there a way to make the second test return `true` too?

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are modifying the `innerHTML` property. After that browser creates another `li` element, and as every object is unique, the generated `li` element is not equal to the previous `li` element. You can append a `textNode` instead of modifying the `innerHTML` property:

```
playlist.appendChild(document.createTextNode('some text'));
```

Comment: What is instead of 'some text', there is '<hr>'. How to handle both these cases?

Comment: @name Do you want to append a `hr` element instead of the textNode? In that case you use `createElement` instead of the `createTextNode` as you have already done it. Note that `ul` element should only have `li` childNodes. You should at first append a `li` element and then append the `hr` to it.

Comment: No, I mean, what to do, when I need to append 'some<br>text<hr>'?

Answer (score 0):

The use of `innerHTML` makes the browser parse and regenerate the DOM. Newly created objects are not the same object, despite their content may be equivalent.

When you use `console.log(li)` or `console.log(playlist.children[0])` the browser converts the objects to textual representations that can be displayed, they display the same text but they are not the same object.

There's a trick to make the comparison return true:

```
console.log(""+playlist.children[0] == ""+li); // always return true
```

What that does is implicitly convert the objects to strings before comparing them. Then the resulting strings, as you were claiming are equal (but not the original objects they came from).

If you compare at `innerHTML` level they are also equal:

```
console.log(playlist.children[0].innerHTML == li.innerHTML); // always return true
```